.Net Scraping Wordpress website 429 too many request
I would like my users to add website links and retreive metadata from it.
For exemple, title, description, og:image, etc...
I used WebClient or HttpClient to first retrive the HTML content.
Then I parse it with regex or htmlutilitypack
Last I download the og:image.
The code look like :
var client = new WebClient(); 
var htmlContent = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
 ...Html Parsing... 
var imgData = await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(imageUrl);

It works well for most of websites but with wordpress website I've got 429 too many requests.
Only Two calls are made. Any idea why it doesn't work?

You'll probably have to ask the owner of the website.

You are scraping others' site so be nice to others' website by setting up intervals between HTTP requests.You may also need to change your UA and IP address, depending on how website owner counters web scrapers.

In theory, it's website owner that put his website. I need to put more than 30s off between my 2 calls to avoid the error. It's just, I find strange that a browser can refresh n time with short delay a page without problem and cannot not make 2 calls. Maybe there is some security check with the clientagent

Or perhaps you've scraped it many times in the past, and it's remembered that you're a repeat offender and has severely rate-limited you. Or maybe it's running some detection (UA, javascript, etc) and can tell that you're not a real browser
